# How to read/write protocol buffer messages with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, protocol-buffers, sequencefile

I want to Read/write protocol buffer messages from/to HDFS with Apache Spark. I found these suggested ways:

1) Convert protobuf messsages to Json with Google's Gson Library and then read/write them by SparkSql. This solution is explained in [this link](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/129/how-do-i-use-sparksql-with-protocol-buffers.html) But I think doing that (convert to json) is an extra task.

2) Convert to Parquet file. There are [**parquet-mr**](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) and [**sparksql-protobuf**](https://github.com/saurfang/sparksql-protobuf)  github projects for this way but I don't want parquet file because I always work with all columns (not some columns) and in this way Parquet Format does not give me any gain (at least I think).

3) [ScalaPB](https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB). May be it's what I am looking for. but in scala language that I don't know anything about it. I am looking for a java-based solution. [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSq_6Ws16gw) introduce scalaPB and explain how to use it (for scala developers).

4) Through the use of the sequence file and this is what I looking for, but found nothing about that. So, my question is: How can I write protobuf messages to sequence file on HDFS and from that? Any other suggestion will be useful.

5) Through twitter's [Elephant-bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird) Library.

Answer (score 1):

Though a bit hidden between the points, you seem to be asking how to write to a sequencefile in spark. I found an example [here](http://discuss.itversity.com/t/reading-and-writing-sequence-files/11126).

```
// Importing org.apache.hadoop.io package
import org.apache.hadoop.io._

// As we need data in sequence file format to read. Let us see how to write first
// Reading data from text file format
val dataRDD = sc.textFile("/public/retail_db/orders")

// Using null as key and value will be of type Text while saving in sequence file format
// By Int and String, we do not need to convert types into IntWritable and Text
// But for others we need to convert to writable object
// For example, if the key/value is of type Long, we might have to 
// type cast by saying new LongWritable(object)
dataRDD.
  map(x => (NullWritable.get(), x)).
  saveAsSequenceFile("/user/`whoami`/orders_seq")
// Make sure to replace `whoami` with the appropriate OS user id

// Saving in sequence file with key of type Int and value of type String
dataRDD.
  map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toInt, x.split(",")(1))).
  saveAsSequenceFile("/user/`whoami`/orders_seq")
// Make sure to replace `whoami` with the appropriate OS user id
```